# Parallel programming on Binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, parallel-processing, binary-tree, python-multiprocessing

I'm quite new to python and parallel programming. I have a binary tree that looks like this:
[image: binary tree]

My task is to square each node and replace the value in the node, but the children nodes must be squared *before* the parent nodes (i.e. All the children tasks should be executed before the parent tasks - 4,5,6 & 7 will get squared first then 2 & 3 using threads ), and all nodes of the same level should undergo the squaring task parallel.

How do I apply this function on each node parallelly?
By parallel, I mean to use the multiprocessing aspect of python.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But I'm sure that's not what you are looking for. Please rephrase the question to highlight what you want to know.

Comment: I want to apply this parallelly running function on the tree structure

Comment: and? What is stopping you?

Comment: Binary Tree or B-Tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that squares each level before its parent levels. It first finds the levels, and then starts from the lowest level to square each level:

```
from Queue import Queue

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.v = value
        self.l = None
        self.r = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.v)

def square(node): 
    level = [node]
    levels = [level]
    while level:
        new_level = []
        for n in level:
            if n.l:
                new_level.append(n.l)
            if n.r:
                new_level.append(n.r)    
        if new_level:
            levels.append(new_level)
        level = new_level
    #print levels

    for level in reversed(levels):
        #print level
        square_level(level)

def square_level(level):
    for node in level:
        node.v *= node.v

def print_tree(node):
    q = Queue()
    q.put(node)
    while not q.empty(): 
        n = q.get()
        print n
        if n.l:
            q.put(n.l)
        if n.r:
            q.put(n.r)

n1 = Node(1)
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(3)
n4 = Node(4)
n5 = Node(5)
n6 = Node(6)
n7 = Node(7)

n1.l = n2
n1.r = n3
n2.l = n4
n2.r = n5
n3.l = n6
n3.r = n7

print_tree(n1)        
square(n1)
print "squared:"
print_tree(n1)
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
squared:
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
```

Now if you need to run each level in parallel, replace the square_level function with the paralleled implementation.

So the multithreaded version would like this:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.v = value
        self.l = None
        self.r = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.v)

def square(node): 

    # find levels
    level = [node]
    levels = [level]
    while level:
        new_level = []
        for n in level:
            if n.l:
                new_level.append(n.l)
            if n.r:
                new_level.append(n.r)    
        if new_level:
            levels.append(new_level)
        level = new_level
    #print levels

    # square each level, starting with the lowest level first 
    for level in reversed(levels):
        #print level
        square_level(level)

def square_level(level):
    for node in level:
        q.put(node)
    q.join()

def print_tree(node):
    q = Queue()
    q.put(node)
    while not q.empty(): 
        n = q.get()
        print n
        if n.l:
            q.put(n.l)
        if n.r:
            q.put(n.r)

q = Queue()
def worker():
    while True:
        node = q.get()
        node.v *= node.v
        q.task_done()

for i in range(0, 3):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

n1 = Node(1)
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(3)
n4 = Node(4)
n5 = Node(5)
n6 = Node(6)
n7 = Node(7)

n1.l = n2
n1.r = n3
n2.l = n4
n2.r = n5
n3.l = n6
n3.r = n7

print_tree(n1)        
square(n1)
print "squared:"
print_tree(n1)
```

And it will print the same output like the previous single threaded one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by parallel you simply mean that all the nodes of a depth level must be computed before a lower depth level, i.e. that you don't care about multiple threads.

The standard way to perform an operation on the nodes of a binary tree is to use a recursive function. However, in this case, you'll have to keep track of the depth level to know if you are allowed to perform the task.

You could use a list of tasks to be performed in the right order: you go through your tree, appending the nodes to the list of task. This list is sorted according to the depth of the nodes. At the end, you apply your operation on each node of the sorted list in the given order.

```
def fill_list(node, depth): 
   list.add_in_sorted_list(node, depth)

   if(node.has_left_child())
       fill_list(node.left_child, depth+1)

   if(node.has_right_child())
       fill_list(node.right_child, depth+1)
```

Then apply square() to all the nodes of list.

(this is pseudo code. Complexity O(n^2), but you can get O(n log n) if you use a better structure to handle the sorted tasks, such as another binary tree)

Not that this would not work if you needed info from the children nodes to perform the operation on the current node.

EDIT: The complexity is actually O(n): as you add the current node before calling the function on the children node, you ensure that the current depth is lower than all the future ones. Therefore you can always add the node on the front of the list, which costs O(1).

This wouldn't have been the case if you were calling the function on the children nodes before adding the current node to the list.

Comment: How is this O(n^2)? Wouldn't this be n + n = O(n) ?

Comment: Because adding an element to a sorted list costs O(n). It would be O(log n) on a binary tree.